# Is there a way to update any combination of columns on a table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

Is there an efficient way to update any combination of columns on a table?

For example, if you take the `Employees` table below. I've given some example updates that may occur on this table. As a table's size grows, so would the potential number of unique update conditions.

`| EmployeeId | EmployeeName | TeamName | Title | ReportingManager | Salary |`

Some examples of functionality using the table above:

- Employee is promoted: Update `Title` and `Salary`
- Employee changes team under same reporting manager: Update `TeamName`
- Employee changes team under different reporting manager: Update `TeamName` and `ReportingManager`
- Employee's gets new reporting manager: Update `ReportingManager`
- Employee changes name: Update `EmployeeName`

I've heard about using a TVP with every column from the table listed out. The TVP also has a bit flag to signify that the column in question has changed and then a value field that holds the new value to update the column with. Something like this:

```
| ColumnName | WasValueChanged | Value |
| EmployeeName | 0 | NULL |
| TeamName | 1 | Team B |
| Title | 0 | NULL |
| ReportingManager | 1 | John Smith |
| Salary | 0 | NULL |
```

This gets the job done, but it doesn't seem like the cleanest solution. And when saving and retrieving data in C#, is there a way to accomplish this without using a DataTable or passing around the entire `Employee` object?

Comment: I'd recommend you look into an ORM like EntityFramework, so that you can manipulate rows in the table as if they were properties on an object without having to write a new stored procedure for each or use DataTables.

Comment: We use Dapper, but we also have standards that specify that we should always write stored procedures (as opposed to letting Dapper handle it behind the scenes). From what you're saying it sounds like maybe that's the issue.

Comment: Right, I think for CRUD operations there's not much reason to write a stored procedure but your company's standards are what they are. I'd ask someone else how they deal with this situation because it must be annoying for all sorts of devs you work with.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've had a thorough look around our code base and the go-to solution seems to be to create a new method for each unique combination of fields to be updated. The TVP solution I mentioned is the only attempt I've seen to condense the update process into a single path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a table value parameter is a decent solution in my opinion. Somehow you need to tell the procedure which columns to update and their value. One option if the fields are not nullable would be:

```
create procedure employee_update
    @title nvarchar(100) =null,
    @teamName nvarchar(100)=null
as
update employee
set title=case when(@title is null) then title else @title end,
    teamname=case when (@teamname is null) then teamname else @teamname end
```

Another option would be to pass the data in as a blob such as JSON or XML, then you could do the same logic;however, I still think the TVP is cleaner

Answer (score 1):

You could simply update all columns every time. You just update with the same values when the data doesn't change.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateEmployee(
     @EmployeeId        int,
     @EmployeeName      varchar(250),
     @TeamName          varchar(250),
     @Title             varchar(250),
     @ReportingManager  int,
     @Salary            decimal(18,4)
)

UPDATE Employees SET
    EmployeeName      = ISNULL( @EmployeeName    , EmployeeName    ),
    TeamName          = ISNULL( @TeamName        , TeamName        ),
    Title             = ISNULL( @Title           , Title           ),
    ReportingManager  = ISNULL( @ReportingManager, ReportingManager),
    Salary            = ISNULL( @Salary          , Salary          )
WHERE EmployeeId = @EmployeeId;
```

However, you might be missing something important. In order to keep track of these changes and keeping information reliable, you need an additional table that can keep track of all the changes. Imagine that a manager has excellent results, so he's moved to a knew team that hasn't done great. Right after that, someone looks at results by teams and shows this manager with poor results due to his new team. This ends up on the manager getting fired or losing a bonus.

You need to make sure that your database can show accurate history and information is reliable. This can't be achieved taking shortcuts. Make a new procedure for each event, but more importantly, get someone to properly design the database.

Comment: The Employee table was an example I came up with to demonstrate the issues I was running into. I completely agree on the table design comment. I alluded to updating all of the columns in the post where I mentioned passing around the Employee object. The issue I run into there is that the code initiating the update of the ReportingManager, for example, doesn't have or need access to the rest of the Employee object, it just knows an employee with X EmployeeId or Y EmpoyeeName needs to be updated with the new ReportIngManager. So it wouldn't have all of the other values to pass in when updating.

Comment: In the end, you're always affecting the row, which means that you have to modify a page (or more in case of splits). The advantage of sending less values is minimal. However, the idea of making procedures based on processes and not on tables is the way to go, imho.